# Accessing static website in S3 bucket through Cloudflare with Full SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hosting, cloudflare, cloud-hosting

I have been trawling forums, blog posts, technical places and I've also got in touch with Cloudflare support and I'm no further forward with this. Cloudflare says that AWS is not accepting the host headers for `mine.mydomain.com` and returning 403.

I have an S3 bucket setup called `mine.mydomain.com`, with static website hosting turned on. It gives me an AWS URL to use which works fine to browse the site and any pages within it.

I have created a CNAME record on Cloudflare for `mine` to point to the AWS URL of the bucket. However when I try to browse to the site using `mine.mydomain.com` I get Access Denied errors.

What I have been told is that because we're using full SSL I need to create an empty bucket called `mine-abc` (it could actually be anything I just used that name - just as long as it doesn't have dots in it) and map the CNAME record in Cloudflare to `mine-abc.s3.amazonaws.com`. When I do that I still get an Access Denied error for `mine.mydomain.com`. However if I go to `mine.mydomain.com/index.html` it works. It's also the same if I go to the root of URL I get Access Denied (ie. `mine.mydomain.com/issues`) but if I go to a page (ie. `mine.mydomain.com/issues/index.html`) it again works.

So I'm a little stumped.

Configuration for the `mine.mydomain.com` bucket is:

`` Public Access Settings - all False
Access Control List - Default
Bucket Policy - effectively Allow "arn:aws:s3:::mine.mydomain.com" (and `"mine.mydomain.com/*"`)
CORS Configuration - Allow GET and HEAD for `.mydomain.com and mydomain.com ``

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Comment: One forum article suggests the index.html automatic redirect in S3 buckets only happens when you don't have SSL - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=803974&tstart=0. I don't see it mentioned here though: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html. It could be CloudFlare, CloudFront, and S3 are needed to get this working.

Comment: That is helpful, thanks. At the moment I am able to browse the Cloudfront URL directly (ie. xyz.cloudfront.net). I have set this Cloudfront URL as the CNAME in Cloudflare. I still cannot browse the URL using the Cloudflare DNS name (ie. `mine.mydomain.com`) - I get a 403 error 'generated by Cloudfront').
I think the next stage may be to get the SSL cert (for `mydomain.com`) imported into AWS.